# xampp include doesn't work

Tags: php, include, localhost

Good morning at all! I have an issue that I don't understand.I've XAMPP 
localhost files where include function doesn't work in one file, while 
in other files works without problems.I'm running Chrome browser. I've 
already tried to clear browser cache, but issue still exists. Why?

Include function works in this pages:
`"index.php"`,
`"blog.php"`,
`"history.php"`

Include function doesn't work only on this page:
`contacts.php`
The code is here:

```
<?php include('include/menu.php'); ?>
```

Comment: Don't post code as image. Paste it into your post directly. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Check your error logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need your absolute path to the include file correct by prefixing with `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`;

In all your includes() **do :**

```
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/include/menu.php');
```

Answer (score 1):

it would help to know two things: 1) where are the files located in? 2) what is the error message?

maybe the solution is simple since there is only the lack of the correct path:

```
include(__DIR__."/blog.php");
```

etc.

`__DIR__` contains the path of the current script and is very useful to go up/down the directories based on it.

Comment: All php files I'm working on are in XAMPP/htdocs folders. only menu.php is on htdocs/include/menu.php

Comment: use `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(~0);` for turning on outputting error messages. I guess that there is an syntax error in your contacts.php that causes a fatal error and therefore forces the include() to stop.

Comment: It seems file is included but is hidden, not visible.

Comment: In php log I received this message [28-Mar-2018 10:55:11 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening 'menu.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php') in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/contacts.php on line 54

Comment: there you go :)
line 54 in your contacts.php might tell you more about why it fails

Comment: @ElisaLtc This error tells you, that a file named `menu.php` could not be found in any of the folders `.` (current folder) or `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php`. You will need to specfiy the path to the included PHP file.

Answer (score -1):

I've solved issue. I copied another existent page such as index.php with menu and footer correctly included, and I changed the body content and now it works.